# How do I print the maximum sequence of 8 bits?

Tags: verilog

I have a module with an input of maximum 32 bits and an output of 8 bits. I need to find the 8-bit sequence with the highest value present in my input.

This is what I came up with. After I run it, it gives me a sequence of 8 'X'.

```
module exercitiul4(input [31:0] inpt, output [7:0] otpt);
  
  reg [7:0] maxval;
  
      always @ (inpt) begin
        
          maxval = inpt[7:0]>maxval?inpt[7:0]:maxval;
          maxval = inpt[15:8]>maxval?inpt[15:8]:maxval;
          maxval = inpt[23:16]>maxval?inpt[23:16]:maxval;
          maxval = inpt[31:24]>maxval?inpt[31:24]:maxval;
          
      end
        assign otpt = maxval;
endmodule

module exercitiul4_tb;

reg[31:0] nr_tb;
wire[7:0] out_tb;

exercitiul4 maTerminaProgramuAsta(.inpt(nr_tb), .otpt(out_tb));
initial begin
  nr_tb = 128;
  #1;
  $display("%b", out_tb);
end
endmodule
```

Comment: I expect the code to show me 128 in binary but all i get after compiling and running my simulation is XXXXXXXX. Basically i enter a decimal number and i need to find the maximum 8 bit sequence in that number.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `maxval` as type `reg`, which means it is initialized to X at time 0.

It remains at X because you do not directly assign it any other value.  Since the comparisons, like `inpt[7:0]>maxval`, also return X, `maxval` always stays X.

One way to initialize `maxval` is to directly assign it to the first input value:

```
  always @ (inpt) begin
      maxval = inpt[7:0];
      maxval = inpt[15:8]>maxval?inpt[15:8]:maxval;
      maxval = inpt[23:16]>maxval?inpt[23:16]:maxval;
      maxval = inpt[31:24]>maxval?inpt[31:24]:maxval;
  end
```